# Date closest but earlier than a given date based on another factor

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

My data is similar to the following:

```
data.frame(date=c("2013-07","2013-08","2013-09","2013-11",
              "2013-11","2013-11","2014-02","2014-03"),
       X=c("0","1","0","0","1","0","1","0"))

  date    x 
1 2013-07 0 
2 2013-08 1
3 2013-09 0 
4 2013-11 0 
5 2013-11 1
6 2013-11 0
7 2014-02 1
```

I want to create a new feature that shows the data that is **not later than the current date but the closest from the current date when x=1**

```
date      x  lastdate
1 2013-07 0       NA
2 2013-08 1  2013-08
3 2013-09 0  2013-08
4 2013-11 0  2013-11
5 2013-11 1  2013-11
6 2013-11 0  2013-11
7 2014-02 1  2014-02
8 2014-03 0  2014-02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One efficient solution could be using `fintInterval` and search only within `x == "1"`. I've added `NA_character_` at the beginning for case when `findInterval` returns a zero (like in your first row)

**Some methodology explnation:**

The basic idea here is to add an `NA` at the beginning of `df$date[df$X == "1"]` and then search within the original `df$date[df$X == "1"]` vector. Whenever a value in `df$date` is prior to all values in `df$date[df$X == "1"]`, `findInterval` assign it a `0`. This zero should become `NA` eventually, hence we are adding `+1` to all the incidents found by `findInterval` and search within the new vector (which contains `NA`). This way, all `0`s become `1`s and hence, they are being assigned `NA`s because `NA` is the first value in the new vector.

```
df[["lastdate"]] <- c(NA_character_, 
                      as.character(df$date[df$X == "1"]))[findInterval(df$date, df$date[df$X == "1"]) + 1]
df
#      date X lastdate
# 1 2013-07 0     <NA>
# 2 2013-08 1  2013-08
# 3 2013-09 0  2013-08
# 4 2013-11 0  2013-11
# 5 2013-11 1  2013-11
# 6 2013-11 0  2013-11
# 7 2014-02 1  2014-02
# 8 2014-03 0  2014-02
```

Or (this has a `dplyr` tag)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(lastdate = c(NA_character_, as.character(date[X == "1"]))[findInterval(date, date[X == "1"]) + 1])
```

As a side note it would be probably easier to work with a `numeric` `X` rather a `character` one, and either `character` or a `zoo::yearmon` rather a `factor` (which is hard to modify) `date` column

Comment: Would it be possible to add an explanation about how the logic in your statement is able to build that "lastdate" vector appropriately? I have spent and hour and change trying to piece together how `findInterval()` and that statement works together. Unfortunately I can't seem to wrap my head around how base R's conditional logic decides to pull from the "1" vector or to instead pull from the 'findInterval+1' vector.

Comment: @leerssej I've added an explanation- hope it is clearer now. Just as side note, whenever you don'e understand a certain code, you can brake it to pieces first. For instance, you could start by looking at `findInterval(df$date, df$date[df$X == "1"]) + 1` and etc.

Comment: Thank you. I had broken it up into all its own components; several times actually. All the individual pieces weren't adding up though. Your explanation is helpful, as I think I now understand that your solution appears to nest its vectors more or less: iteratively adding to its 'top' as it finds values that are prior to its first?

Comment: @leerssej Not sure what you mean by "*nest*". It just uses `findInterval` to find intervals within `df$X == "1"` ranges and assigns `NA`s to anything that happened before the first occasion of `df$X == "1"`